# How to build nested query in Elasticsearch to Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I build this elasticsearch query on Java.This is my query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "myField",
                    "query": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "myField.id"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My mapping like this:

```
"myField": {
   "type": "nested",
   "properties": {
      "id": {
         "type": "text",
         "fields": {
            "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I trust recently work with elastic. So hope you guys help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create query like below:

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("userdoc");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .mustNot(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("myField", QueryBuilders.existsQuery("myField.id"),ScoreMode.None));
searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```